# Debugging Windows XP guest using virtual serial port

Tags: debugging, tcp, windbg, qemu, virtual-serial-port

I am trying to debug my Windows XP guest kernel over a QEmu virtual serial port.

I am following ["Setting up the target VM" (linux-kvm.org)](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/WindowsGuestDrivers/UpdatedGuestDebugging#Setting_up_the_target_VM) to setup the debugee by using

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \-m 1024 \-drive file=win-target.img \-serial tcp:127.0.0.1:4445
```

The problem is that QEmu fails to start with the error message

> qemu-system-x86_64: -serial tcp:127.0.0.1:portNo: host and/or port not specified
>   qemu: could not connect serial device to character backend 'tcp:127.0.0.1:portNo'

Though I can successfully create the debugger VM just by adding `serve,nowait` after `tcp:ip:portNumber`.

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

i have not gone through the link and i dont use tcp and ports but i regularly debug xp64 virtual machine from a xp32 physical host using qemu

for network i use tap adapter

and the bat file i use for both debug as well as non debug Qemu session is as below
the qemu is very old one 0.9.0 for windows

```
    during kernel debugging the windbg tends to be terminated several times   
    during startup (enabling DEBUG_SPEW ctrl+alt+d and enabling a log prior  
    to startup of vm shows too much commands in serial pipe restarting   
    kd connection error but i couldnt find anything relevent to solve the issue    
    i simply restart the vm with the bat after a few restarts of the batfile    
    windbg starts running and then there is no problems of windbg  termination
```

contents of bat file

```
IF "%1" == ""       goto nodebug
IF "%1" == "dbg"    goto debug

:nodebug
%cd%\qemu-system-x86_64.exe -L . -m 700 -hda xp64.img -net nic,model=rtl8139 -net tap,ifname=mytap -localtime
goto exit

:debug
%cd%\qemu-system-x86_64.exe -L . -m 700 -hda xp64.img -net nic,model=rtl8139 -net tap,ifname=mytap -localtime -serial pipe:debugPipe
goto exit

:exit
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I am specifically looking to debug over tcp connection.